# How is access denied on Avira file ipmgui.exe?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, acl, avira, cacls

I can't modify anything of the ACL of the `ipmgui.exe` file (or any file of Avira in the same directory).

It's not working at all with any `cacls` line tried, even under a system prompt!  I'm not sure at all it's related to ACL, as they are looking simple. Maybe a protection from Avira?

Here are the `cacls` dumps.

```
cacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\Avira\AntiVir Desktop\ipmgui.exe"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Avira\AntiVir Desktop\ipmgui.exe AUTORITE NT\System:(ID)F
    BUILTIN\Administrators:(ID)F
    BUILTIN\Users:(ID)R
    APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGE:(ID)R

C:\Program Files (x86)\Avira
    BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)R
    BUILTIN\Administrators:(ID)F
    CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(ID)F
    AUTORITE NT\System:(OI)(CI)(ID)F
    BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(ID)(Special access:)
        READ_CONTROL
        SYNCHRONIZE
        FILE_GENERIC_READ
        FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
        FILE_READ_DATA
        FILE_WRITE_DATA
        FILE_APPEND_DATA
        FILE_READ_EA
        FILE_WRITE_EA
        FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
        FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES
    BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(ID)R
    NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(CI)(ID)F
```

I'm using Windows 8.1 up to date.

Comment: If you want to change ACL of ipmgui.exe to get rid of ad popups, it might be a short term solution - next time Avira might update it readjust ACL as it needs. A more clever solution is to add ipmgui.exe to Windows firewall forbidden apps - thus it won't be able to receive advertisements from its web site and should keep silent. I have heard that it works, but I'm not sure if it is permanent.

Answer (score 1):

The self-protecting option of your Avira software is activated. See Option -> General -> Security. You must disable this option, run the script and activate the option again for your own safety.

Comment: Sounds right to me. Norton Security has a similar option called "Norton Tamper Protection" that does basically the same thing. It's intended to prevent malware from disabling or interfering with the AV software.

Answer (score 1):

Even if this is an older question there are still many users running Avira free antivirus and the ipmgui.exe-problem is really annoying.

Because regardless of setting up a windows firewall rule for ipmgui.exe the process will be started periodically i found it is a perfectly working solution to install Bill2´s Process Manager (https://www.bill2-software.com/processmanager/download-en.shtml) and there you can easily create a rule for ipmgui.exe to kill the process swiftly when it´s started. Additionally you can configure a tooltip to be shown in systray when this happens and you can see statistics for process executions and much more.

Feel free to donate, and no i´m not Bill or the one who created this practical piece of software. Btw, thanks Bill (or whoever developed the tool)!